# What events can cause ferror to return non-zero?

Tags: c, file-io, error-handling

What events can cause `ferror()` to return non-zero and after what events should one check `ferror()`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/

Opening, reading, closing?

Will the return value of `ferror()` ever change spontaneously? E.g., if a program checks `ferror(stream)`, takes a nap without interacting with the `FILE` object associated with `stream`, and then checks `ferror(stream)` again, will the return value ever be different?

Is any of this mandated by standards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is primarily errors returned from the underlying system calls (e.g. `read`, `write`, `lseek`, `close`) that will cause the stream's error bit to be set.

Many `f___()` functions from `stdio.h` indicate that if the end-of-file is reached, or an error occurs,  `ferror()` or `feof()` will indicate why.  [`fscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html), for example:

> The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before
>          either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
>          `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>          indicator for the stream (see `ferror(3)`) is set, and `errno` is set
>          indicate the error.

Functions from `stdio.h` are synchronous - there's no background thread doing anything, so no, the error bit (returned from `ferror()`) will never spontaneously change. It will only be affected by a call to libc by your application.

---

For the very curious, one could clone the GLibc Git repository (`git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git`) and have a look at the code itself.

`ferror()` essentially just checks for the `_IO_ERR_SEEN` bit in the file's `_flags` field.  `grep`ing for that constant will show you all of the places it is set/cleared.