# How to signal an error in a file for ferror

Tags: c, file, getc, ferror

Suppose I have this code:

```
FILE *myfile=fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
if (!myfile) {...}
while (1) {
  int c = getc(myfile);
  if (ferror (myfile)) {
      perror ("get c error");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (c == EOF){
      printf ("%s\n" , "the end");
      break;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to cause an error in the file manually , so `ferror` is true, without changing the mode in `fopen` to "w"? (This would cause an error because we opened `myfile` in write mode , but we read with `getc`.

Comment: "Is there a way to cause an error in the file manually" --> I do not know of one - other than a change of file mode.  I suspect it would be implementation dependent.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717132/what-events-can-cause-ferror-to-return-non-zero